# SQL request to export abandoned cart in Prestashop

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I'm looking for a request to export abandoned cart in Prestashop.
To start I tried this : SELECT * FROM `ps_cart` WHERE checkout_session_data is not null
but I would like to join the name and email.
Anyone already did it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"SELECT ps_cart.*, firstname, lastname, email FROM ps_cart INNER JOIN ps_customer ON ps_customer.id_customer = ps_cart.id_customer WHERE checkout_session_data IS NOT NULL"
```